# Inheritance / "Componization" in WPF views

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, mvvm

Assume I have several Views in my WPF application that all show a report, but each View shows a different report.
I created a base ViewModel that contains all the stuff all reports have in common. Each report View gets its own ViewModel that is derived from the base ViewModel. These derived ViewModels have the following responsibilities:

1. Generate the Report Data
2. Format the Report Data for printing
3. Provide properties for the report parameters
4. Provide Commands for additional actions that can be executed on the generated report (optional)

That's all fine and concise, however, the Views are a complete mess.
Basically, each View is the same with only some minor changes, for example:

1. Provide different controls for the report parameters
2. Provide buttons that bind to the Commands for the additional actions

**I would like to achieve the following:**

1. Have a base View that defines all the stuff all report Views have in common, similar to a Site.master in ASP.NET. This would contain the search button, the print button, the grid the report is shown in etc...
2. Have concrete Views - one for each report - that defines only the controls for the search parameters and the buttons for the additional actions

How to do this? Googling for WPF master page brings up a lot of custom made solutions - surely there must be a standard way?

Comment: CAF GUI or PRISM use this master region and local region concept dont they? Cant you use that?

Comment: I don't use these frameworks, so I don't think I can utilize this concept.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In WPF, a placeholder `ContentControl.ContentTemplate` can be set automatically based on its `DataTemplate.DataType` if the `Content` is set to that same `DataType` instance.

http://www.japf.fr/2009/03/thinking-with-mvvm-data-templates-contentcontrol/

Comment: +1, this is usually what I do. I'll create a single view for all the ViewModels, and either use `ContentControls`/`DataTemplates` for specific data, or `DataTriggers` w/ an `ObjectToTypeConverter` which returns the type of an object. I can then use a Trigger based on if the converted value is equal to `{x:Type local:MyViewModelA}`

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure that this is the standard way to create composite views, but I've had some success defining a master view (a `Window` in my case) that contains the common controls needed by a family of views and injecting a different `UserControl` for each different sub-view into the master by using a `ContentControl` as the equivalent to a `ContentPlaceholder` in an ASP.NET masterpage. In my case, I've defined an interface that all sub-views implement:

```
public interface ISubView
{
   BaseViewModel ViewModel { get; set; }
}
```

This allows my `ApplicationController` to push the view model into the child view when handling a request to show a particular view. The sub-view is then composed with the master view via a setter property on the master view before being shown.

The `ApplicationController` is the class that centralizes the tasks of opening and closing views; whenever anything in the application wants to show a particular view it asks the `ApplicationController`. When it receives a request to show a particular view it looks up and constructs the corresponding sub-view and View Model sub-class from an internal "registry", and composes the parts together. At application start-up you create the `ApplicationController` and register the combinations of ViewModel subclass and View subclass. A partial example implementation is:

```
public class ApplicationController
{

   private IDictionary<string, Tuple<Func<ISubView>, Func<BaseViewModel>> _registry;
   private Func<IShellWindow> _shellActivator;

   public ApplicationController(Func<IShellWindow> shellActivator)
   {
      _registry = new Dictionary<string, Tuple<Func<ISubView>, Func<BaseViewModel>>();
      _shellActivator = shellActivator;
   }

   public void RequestShow(string viewName)
   {
      var shell = _shellActivator(); 
      var viewToModel = _registry[viewName];
      var view = viewToModel.Item1();
      var viewModel = viewToModel.Item2();
      view.ViewModel = viewModel;
      shell.Display(view);
   }

   public Register(string name, Func<ISubView> subViewCreator, Func<ViewModel> viewModelCreator)
   {
      _registry.Add(name, new Tuple(subViewCreator, viewModelCreator));
   }
}
```

In the shell's `Display` method (defined on the IShellView interface) you'd do something like:

```
   public void Display(ISubView view)
   {
      contentHolder.Content = view;
      DataContext = view.ViewModel;
      Show();
   }
```

The application start-up would include something like:

```
var appController = new ApplicationController(() => new ShellWindow());
appController.Register("EmployeesReport", () => new EmployeesReportView(), () => new EmployeesReportViewModel);
appController.Register("OrdersReport", () => new OrdersReportView(), () => new OrdersReportViewModel());

//etc.
```

Comment: How is this injection of the user control into the content control working? Who does this?

Comment: I've expanded the answer to include more about the ApplicationController's role.

Comment: This to me look like a custom CAF GUI implementation. It has shell that maintains a registry dictionary of views and their models (in case of CAF GUI thats regions)

Comment: The implementation I'm using is fairly lightweight because it's tailored precisely to my needs. I've incorporated other concepts not shown in the example as I need them such as ViewLifeCycle and ShellActivator classes which was easy to do since it's code I control.

Comment: Thanks for your extensive answer. However, I went with the approach from AngelWPF.